# Landscape to portrait view is causing empty space on the page

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, fullpage.js, landscape-portrait

I came across this empty space issue on my site and noticed it is caused by fullpage.js. I believe this issue is only happening on Safari and I've tested it on an iPhone 6s.

Reproduce:

- When viewing a fullpage.js site, rotate your device to landscape view
- Then rotate back to portrait view and notice white space on bottom of the screen

I also noticed, if you tap near the address bar the section seems to scroll back into place.

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There has been a new release today, fullpage.js 3.1.0 You can try with that: https://unpkg.com/fullpage.js@3.1.0/dist/fullpage.min.js

Are you still able to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I will try updating my site, thank you. Is this site currently updated to the recent fullpage version? https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ . Because the issue is still happening there

Comment: Will the new fullpage.js update work with the react-fullpage wrapper?

Comment: I didn't noticed you were using react. Sure, I'll be updating the react wrapper tomorrow and I'll let you know when done! ;)

Comment: no worries, please let me know!

Comment: Ok, just published the update. react-fullpage@0.1.19 containing fullPage.js 3.1.0.

Comment: Just updated my site but the issue with empty space is still happening

Comment: Yeah that it might be related with this bug: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues

Answer (score 0):

Add the `afterResize` method to your Fullpage.js config options with a callback that triggers the Fullpage API's `reBuild` method. In vanilla JS, that would look like this:

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  afterResize() {
    const fp = document.querySelector('#fullpage')
    fp.fullpage_api.reBuild();
  }
});
```

In React, it would look like this:

```
class FullpageWrapper extends React.Component {
  afterResize() {
    this.fp.fullpageApi.reBuild();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactFullpage ref={el => this.fp = el}>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I added that and I'm getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'reBuild' of undefined'. I also tried 'this.fullpage_api.reBuild' and I'm getting the same results. I am using the React wrapper for fullpage.js by the way

Comment: Try it without the `.api`.

Comment: Tried that and got: TypeError: this.reBuild is not a function

Comment: Revised answer above.

Comment: Still getting 'reBuild' undefined. I added your suggestion to this sandbox for testing: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fullpagejs-example-forked-sy1vf?file=/src/index.js

I appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm not much of a React guy, I do Vue myself. But I figured it out and added the answer above.

Comment: I ended up getting this working but it does not seem to solve the issue :/

Comment: Ugh, sorry to hear.